# How to move an object across a game board. Multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, object, button, p5.js

I am an extreme beginner in the field of P5.JS. I am way more knowledgeable in Java which will be apparent in my broken code. I have attempted a multitude of Java approaches to cycling through objects of the same class and applying methods to them. My attempt is to implement buttons that will move them forward as of now and once I understand that move on to more complicated interactions.

https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1564721 6

This is the link to the code I am attempting to fix it currently, but if you have any tips or advice for streamlining this please let me know.

```
    var gridCellSizeX = 80;
    var gridCellSizeY = 100;
    var gridAlpha = 1000;
    let img; 
    var gridCellSizeSlider;
    turnValue = 1; 
    var count = 1; 
    var gameOn = true; 
    var forward = false; 



   function preload() {
   img = loadImage('vagg02.jpg');   
   }

function setup() {
createCanvas(800, 600);
image(img, 0,0,800,500);
image( img ,0, 500, 800,100); 

stroke(0, gridAlpha);

for (var x = 0; x < width; x += gridCellSizeX) {
line(x, 0, x, 500);
}
 for (var y = 0; y < height; y += gridCellSizeY) {
    line(0, y, width, y);
}

token1 = new token(15, 5, 100, 5000, 'reb', 1)
token2 = new token(15, 205, 100, 5000,'reb', 2 )
token3 = new token(15, 405, 100, 5000, 'reb', 3)
token4 = new token(735, 5, 100, 5000,'union', 4)
token5 = new token(735, 205, 100, 5000, 'union', 5)
token6 = new token(735, 405, 100, 5000, 'union', 6)

const tokens = new Array(token1, token2, token3, token4, token5, token6);

forwardButton = createButton('Move -->')
forwardButton.position(300, 525);
forwardButton.mousePressed(moveForward());

//button = createButton('Move -->'); button.position(300, 525);  button.mousePressed();

button2 = createButton('Move Up');
button2.position(400, 525);
button2.mousePressed();

button3 = createButton('Move Down');
button3.position(500, 525);
button3.mousePressed();

button4 = createButton('Move <--');
button4.position(600, 525);
button4.mousePressed();
}


 function draw() {
 if(forward == true) token1.x =+ 500; 


   //for(let i = 0; gameOn == true; i++){ if(i > 6){    i = 0; }}
 }

function mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX >= 300 && mouseX <= 325 && 
    mouseY >= 525 && mouseY <= 500){

       token1.moveForward();
    
     }
return false;
}

 // new file token

class token {

    constructor(xpos, ypos, t, a, s, turn) {
this.x = xpos;
this.y = ypos;
this.troopSize = t / 2;
this.accuracy = a / 100.0;
    this.side = s; 
    this.moveTurn = turn; 
    this.loaded = true;
        
        if(this.side == 'reb'){
fill('red');
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.troopSize, 90)
        }
        
        if(this.side == 'union'){
    fill('blue');
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.troopSize, 90)
        }
}
    
getToken(){
if(count > 6){
    count = 1; 
}
if(count == 1) {
    return token1;
} 
    else if(count == 2){
        return token2;
    }
else if(count == 3){
        return token3;
    }
else if(count == 4){
        return token4;
    }
else if(count == 5){
        return token5;
    }
else if(count == 6){
return token6;
}
count++;
 }
            ///////// Beginning of Basic Functions for the TOKEN CLASS
 moveForward(){
            if(this.side == 'reb'){
        token1.x += 50;
            redraw(token1);
        }
        
        if(this.side == 'union'){
            this.x += -50;
            redraw();
    
        }
    }
    
    ////
    
moveBackward(){
        if(this.side == 'reb'){
        this.x = this.x - 50;
        }
        
        if(this.side == 'union'){
            this.x = this.x + 50;
    
        }
    }
    
    /////
    
    fire(){
        if(loaded == true){
            
        }
    }   
    
    //////
    
    load(){
        
    }
    
    ///////
    
    fixBayonet(){
        
    }
    
    ////////
    
    charge(){
        
    }
    
    ///////// END of Basic Functions for the TOKEN CLASS
}
```

Comment: Please include in your question the relevant code. Links can be interesting, but they can break. For instance, when I click it now, I get "OpenProcessing is getting an upgrade".

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Also Java != JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.